# Checking to see if pip is installed?

Tags: python

Very much a newbie question but it's something that I've come across a few times now... I'm working through a python textbook and it tells me to check which version of pip is installed and has the following command:

```
$ python3 -m pip --version
```

Presumably I should be running this in bash. If so, which folder should I be in? I have anaconda installed if that makes any difference.

(I can check in python which version I have by running pip --version I'm just wondering why the above isn't working)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: pip --version

Comment: If I type python3 -m pip --version in bash then I get an error saying 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @John Wildman, If you go inside python installed directory this command will work. To fix unrecognised python, you need to add python (installed location) to environmental variable.

Comment: To add python path to environment variables, follow this link https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your Anaconda installation is. You should normally be in your user folder. A typical output might go like this:

```
python3 -m pip --version
# pip 19.3.1 from /home/john/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```